# I want to add a info icon to my datatable. When clicked on info icon it should pop up a window to display details

Tags: javascript, python, flask, datatables

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "searching": false,
        "paging":   false,

        ajax: "/auth/get_users",
        columns: [
            { data: "id" },
            { data: "email" },
            { data: "site_url" },
            { data:   "details"
                data:   "status",
                    render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                        if ( type === 'display' ) {
                            if(row.details === true)
                                return '<input type="checkbox"  class="editor-active" checked>';
                            else 
                                return '<input type="checkbox" class="editor-active">';
                        }
                        return data;
                },
                className: "dt-body-center"
            }

            {
                data:   "status",
                render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                    if ( type === 'display' ) {
                        if(row.status === true)
                            return '<input type="checkbox"  class="editor-active" checked>';
                        else 
                            return '<input type="checkbox" class="editor-active">';
                    }
                    return data;
                },
                className: "dt-body-center"
            }
        ],
        rowCallback: function ( row, data ) {
    } 
} );

    $('#example').on( 'change', 'input.editor-active', function () {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    // this row consists of curent checked user
    row = table.row($(this).closest('tr') ).data();
    status = $('.editor-active').prop('checked');
    if (status == "true"){
    // call your authenticate and then signup api call get api-key,and store status and api key in db 
        $.ajax({
        url: '/auth/authenticate',
        data:{'userid':1},
        type: 'GET',
        success:function(response)
        {
        resp = JSON.parse(response);
        token = resp['token'];
        console.log(token);
        sessionStorage.setItem('token',token);
        field = sessionStorage.getItem('token'); 
        $.ajax({
                url : 'http://104.154.251.137/v10/signup',
                data: {'email_address': row.email ,'site_url': row.site_url},
                headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token},
                type: 'POST',
                success:function(response)
                {
                    var apikey = response.api_key;
                    var data = {"status":status,"api_key":apikey,"userid":row.id};
                    $.ajax({
                    url: '/auth/save_details',
                    data: data,
                    type: 'POST',
                    success:function(response)
                    {
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                    });    
                }
            });
        }
    });    
}
});
```

1. This is my JavaScript code to display a data table where I want to add info icon.

   @loginuser.route('/get_users',methods=['GET'])
   def list_users():
       users = User.query.all()
       data = []

   ```
   for user in users:
       if user.id == 1:
           continue

       user_data ={} 
       user_data['id'] = user.id
       user_data['email'] = user.email
       user_data['site_url'] = user.site_url
       user_data['details'] = user.details
       try:
           site = Site.query.get(user.id)
           user_data['status'] = site.status
       except AttributeError:
           user_data['status'] = False 


       data.append(user_data)

       final_data = {'data':data}

   return json.dumps(final_data)
   ```
2. This is my python file where I provide details.

I'm using flask framework for this application.

I am facing some problems adding a info icon in data table. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is no python file where you provide details.

Comment: Apart from flask and python imlementation, [This Example](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-types/bootstrap-modal.html) is using modal to display details of datatable row.